# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to install OpenShift client tools with

```
C:\> gem install rhc
```

but it is giving error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0) in any repository
```

how to avoid it and install rhc.

Comment: Can you tell us what you get if you run "ruby -v" and "gem -v"

Comment: I got the solution .. I used $gem source -a http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 9):

```
gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/
```